# set state in the on change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool jov = false;

class boox extends StatelessWidget {
  const boox({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text("jordn"),
              Checkbox(
                  value: jov,
                  onChanged: (String val) {
                    setstate(() {
                      jov = val;
                    });
                  })
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [Text("data")],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `setstate` cannot appear  on  onchanged and cant take it

I am difintion the variables and the problem still appear

and try to write the code and still appear this problem if any can fix him to me or no way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `StatefulWidget` to use `setState` and `onChanged` will provide nullable bool for `Checkbox` it will be `onChanged: (bool? value) {`

```dart
class boox extends StatefulWidget {
  const boox({super.key});

  @override
  State<boox> createState() => _booxState();
}

class _booxState extends State<boox> {
  bool jov = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text("jordn"),
              Checkbox(
                value: jov,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    jov = value??false;
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [Text("data")],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your example wouldn't work

**boox** is Stateless widget and doesn't have any **setState** method
In your case you can see changes your app should update a tree node which belong **boox** widget

You have to use Stateful widget instead